# How to create one to many generic relation between objects in Django

Tags: django

I have these two models:
How do I correctly set the relationship so I can do backward queries?

```
class Client(models.Model):
      city = models.CharField(max_length=16)
      worker = models.ForeignKey(
        "Worker",
        null=True,
        default="1",
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
        related_name="assigned_workers",
    )
      class Meta:
          abstract = True
```

And:

```
class Worker(models.Model):
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
      gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

What I want to do is set up the models in a way I can do the following queries:

- Query the clients assigned to a worker using the worker object. Something like this:

> Worker.objects.assigned_workers.all()

Comment: Have you read the documentation about `ForeignKey` and the backward relation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: @DrummerMann Yes , maybe I didn't understand it. I know I can use the above foreign key to get the related worker for the client. But I don't know how to get all the clients for a specific worker object.

Comment: Since you defined the related name, you should be able to do `worker.assigned_workers.all()`. Where `worker` is the one object where you will need the clients for

Comment: Oh! That was it. Thanks.